# How does a process like KeePass protect its memory in Windows?

Tags: windows, permissions, encryption, virtual-memory, process-explorer

I am looking at [KeePass](https://keepass.info) and trying to figure out how it protects its memory exactly. Is it because the use of `KeePassLib.Security.ProtectedBinary` class for all it's memory allocations or is it clearing `PROCESS_VM_READ` permissions on the process? Or is it something else?

This is what process explorer shows*

[image]

[*] *Windows is doing some scaling kung-fu, I've not idea how to take a screenshot that is not blurry*

Comment: Go and read the source code ...

Comment: I have done so and asked a question after scanning through the source code